# EAS Build iOS Failure: Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

I'm using EAS to build my Expo app, and today I started getting this error when attempting to run an iOS build, either local or on EAS servers. I'm thinking it's an issue with Apple servers, so I'm hoping it gets fixed soon.

Output from build command:

```
✔ Select platform › iOS
✔ Using remote iOS credentials (Expo server)

If you provide your Apple account credentials we will be able to generate all necessary build credentials and fully validate them.
This is optional, but without Apple account access you will need to provide all the missing values manually and we can only run minimal validation on them.
✔ Do you want to log in to your Apple account? … yes

› Log in to your Apple Developer account to continue
✔ Apple ID: … ...
› Restoring session /Users/.../.app-store/auth/.../cookie
› Session expired Local session
› Using password for ... from your local Keychain
  Learn more
✔ Logged in New session
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
    Error: Cookie not in this host's domain. Cookie:developer-mdn.apple.com Request:developer.apple.com
```

Anyone else have this problem and have any ideas on how to resolve it?

I've tried removing the stored authentication cookie and signing in again. I also tried signing in on App Store Connect to see if there was any issue with my account but I couldn't find one.

**EDIT:** The issue resolved itself after a few days. It was most likely a temporary issue with the EAS servers' connection to Apple.

Comment: Do not put an Answer into the Question.

Answer (score 63):

Updating the eas-cli version to version 3.5.2 fixed the problem for me.
Just run the command:

```
npm install -g eas-cli
```

and it supposed to work

Comment: What's odd about this is that I had just installed eas-cli with that very command. Yet when I ran it, I noticed it was not the latest copy. So I ran the exact SAME command again, and it upgraded it to the latest version, at which point it worked. Go figure.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, does anyone know why this error occurs though?

Answer (score 6):

This is now fixed by the expo team.
In order for it to work, all you have to do is update to the latest eas-cli. This should do it:

```
npm i -g eas-cli
```

Then build or submit you application to iOS.

```
eas build --platform ios --auto-submit
```

Of course you can ignore the --auto-submit.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error. I was able to start the build, after selecting `no` for the `"Do you want to log in to your Apple account?"` question. I hope this workaround works for you.

github issue https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1672#issuecomment-1416851869

Edit: As @Dviros pointed out above, run `npm install -g eas-cli` for a definitive solution.

Comment: This works for the build but submitting the app with EAS is not possible :/

Comment: Yes I was able to build by skipping the sign in, but then I had to make some changes to the configuration of the app's provisioning profile, and now it needs to connect to Apple before it can build. Hopefully it's fixed soon.

Comment: Does not work for me. As soon as I hit "No", it says, No Problem, but asks to log in right away.

Comment: It was fixed in `eas-cli` version `3.5.2`

Comment: Updating the ```eas-cli``` fixed it

Answer (score 4):

I was able to work around the Apple sign in by using local credentials.

https://docs.expo.dev/app-signing/local-credentials/

By going to the Expo website I was able to download the distribution certificate and provisioning profile certificate. There was also a file that had the password needed to access the distribution certificate. Then I configured the production build profile in `eas.json` with

```
...
"ios": {
  "credentialsSource": "local"
},
...
```

And I created a `credentials.json` file with

```
{
  "ios": {
    "provisioningProfilePath": "relative/path/to/provisioning/profile.mobileprovision",
    "distributionCertificate": {
      "path": "relative/path/to/distribution/certificate.p12",
      "password": "<MYPASSWORD>"
    }
  }
}
```

Then building with the normal command, it no longer prompted me to sign in to Apple. Build worked like a charm!

Comment: Thanks @kollin-murphy This worked for me.
The direct link to download Apple dist cert p12 and provisioning profile is: 
https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list

Answer (score 1):

The EXPO team created an incident on there status page regarding this issue:
[Apple authentication error renewing certificates/profiles for EAS Build](https://status.expo.dev/incidents/thkksr16ctcr)

> We are currently investigating an upstream issue authenticating with Apple to renew certificates/profiles when using EAS Build.

> If you are using local credentials, if you're running a non-interactive build, or if you don't need to login to Apple because your certificates/profiles are up to date, then you are unaffected by this incident.

I hope they fix it soon!

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling `eas-cli` globally using `npm i -g eas-cli` *did not fix this problem for me*.

I was able to fix this by updating the `eas-cli` package in my **local project**.

Update your package.json to `"eas-cli": "^3.5.2",` and then run `npm i` to reinstall.

Comment: Thanks it solved this issue for me: Cookie not in this host's domain. Cookie:developer-mdn.apple.com Request:developer.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

use Transporter.

I got the same issue, but i solved it using transporter. I use eas build to upload it to expo server from there i download the app and upload it to Transporter.

Answer (score 0):

when eas build --platform ios , it will ask , select no
✔ Do you want to log in to your Apple account? … no

Answer (score 0):

problem solved with `eas build -p ios --non-interactive` command.

https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/2224